# I get the record when the variable is not initialized/used

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the following CREATED_DATE which is 24/06/2019 01:00:00 , in the database.

If I run the following

```
select * from mytable where CREATED_DATE between to_date('23/06/2019 15:39:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') and  to_date('24/06/2019 17:53:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

Then I get the record I want.

However if I do the following:

```
variable fromDate DATE;
exec :fromDate := to_date('10/06/2019 15:39:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss');

variable toDate DATE;
exec :toDate := to_date('24/06/2019 17:53:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss');

select * from mytable where CREATED_DATE between :fromDate and :toDate
```

Then I don't the record. I am use SQL developer to run the above.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL Developer, which version is it? My SQL Plus (11g XE) and SQL Developer ver. 18.3 say this:

```
SQL> var fromdate date;
Usage: VAR[IABLE] [ <variable> [ NUMBER | CHAR | CHAR (n [CHAR|BYTE]) |
                    VARCHAR2 (n [CHAR|BYTE]) | NCHAR | NCHAR (n) |
                    NVARCHAR2 (n) | CLOB | NCLOB | BLOB | BFILE
                    REFCURSOR | BINARY_FLOAT | BINARY_DOUBLE ] ]
SQL>
```

so ... I'm unable to reproduce what you are saying, it fails at the very first step.

Comment: I am using SQL developer 16.84 and 11g XE database. It is weird you are not able to run it!